# how to optimize subquery mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have the following query, from which I obtain the expected results, the problem is that it takes a long time to return the data, I know that the slowness is due to the following line

```
(select fecha_hora 
 from horas
 where horas.consulta_id = consultas.id
 AND fecha_hora >= NOW() 
 AND horas.estado = 0
 ORDER BY fecha_hora limit 0, 1) as hora
```

What I do not know is how to solve it.

The objective is to obtain the date and time closest to the actual day available that a doctor has (there are doctors who do not have availability)

```
select `medicos`.`id` as `med_id`
, `medicos`.`estado` as `med_estado`
, `medicos`.`descripcion`
, `clinicas`.`nombre` as `cli_nombre`
, `clinicas`.`direccion` as `cli_direccion`
, `regiones`.`nombre` as `region`
, `comunas`.`nombre` as `comuna`
, (select fecha_hora 
   from horas 
   where horas.consulta_id = consultas.id 
   AND fecha_hora >= NOW() 
   AND horas.estado = 0 
   ORDER BY fecha_hora 
   limit 0, 1) as hora
from `consultas` 
inner join `consulta_especialidad` 
 on `consulta_especialidad`.`consulta_id` = `consultas`.`id` 
inner join `especialidades` 
  on `especialidades`.`id` = `consulta_especialidad`.`especialidad_id` 
inner join `medicos` 
  on `medicos`.`id` = `consultas`.`medico_id` 
inner join `clinicas` 
  on `clinicas`.`id` = `consultas`.`clinica_id` 
inner join `regiones` 
  on `regiones`.`id` = `clinicas`.`region_id` 
inner join `comunas` on `comunas`.`id` = `clinicas`.`comuna_id` 
where `medicos`.`estado` != 5 
and `clinicas`.`region_id` = 15 
and `especialidades`.`id` = 116 
group by `medicos`.`id` 
order by `medicos`.`estado` desc
 , -`hora` desc, `medicos`.`nombres` asc
 , `medicos`.`apellidos` asc
```

Comment: This is a dependent or correlated query (the subquery depends on a value from the outer query), so it has to run again and again for each row in the outer query. Ideally you can rewrite it to be an independent query or derived table. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-tables.html for some examples.

Comment: I suggest you start by reading some of the *many* q+a here on query optimization, noting which questions are upvoted, the information supplied in the question and comparing that with the ones which are downvoted and closed. You should also read the FAQ and guidance on how to ask a question. Then try asking asking again, applying what you have learnt.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer. Too long for a comment...

FWIW, I find this easier to read...

```
SELECT m.id med_id
     , m.estado med_estado
     , m.nombre_completo med_nombre_completo
     , m.seguridad med_seguridad
     , m.foto_perfil med_foto_perfil
     , m.genero med_genero
     , m.descripcion
     , l.nombre cli_nombre
     , l.direccion cli_direccion
     , l.id cli_id
     , l.telefono cli_telefono
     , l.link_agenda cli_link_agenda
     , r.nombre region
     , c.nombre comuna
     , (SELECT fecha_hora 
          FROM horas h
         WHERE h.consulta_id = k.id 
           AND fecha_hora >= NOW() 
           AND h.estado = 0 
         ORDER 
            BY fecha_hora 
         LIMIT 0,1
       ) hora
  FROM consultas k
  JOIN consulta_especialidad ke 
    ON ke.consulta_id = k.id 
  JOIN especialidades e
    ON e.id = ke.especialidad_id 
  JOIN medicos m 
    ON m.id = k.medico_id 
  JOIN clinicas l
    ON l.id = k.clinica_id 
  JOIN regiones r
    ON r.id = l.region_id 
  JOIN comunas c 
    ON c.id = l.comuna_id 
 WHERE m.estado != 5 
   AND l.region_id = 15 
   AND e.id = 116 
 GROUP 
    BY m.id 
 ORDER 
    BY m.estado DESC
     , -hora DESC -- ISN'T THIS THE SAME AS ASC???
     , m.nombres ASC
     , m.apellidos ASC
```

An observation: You have a GROUP BY clause, but no aggregating functions. This is a recipe for disaster.